# How to return float value assigned to <li> element

Tags: javascript, html

Working on calculator thing and I need to get float value which I have assigned to each li element. When I try to get the value it returns int. I've already tried `parseFloat`, but did not work. I believe it is easy fix and for sure I've missed something.

```
<li id='1' value='1.0'><a href='#'>No Activity</a></li>
                    <li id='2' value='1.4'><a href='#'>Low Activity</a></li>
                    <li id='3' value='1.8'><a href='#'>Middle Activity</a></li>
                    <li id='4' value='2.2'><a href='#'>High Activity</a></li>
```

Comment: As others have suggested, you can get the desired results by using ```.getAttribute('value')```. Note, however, that, unlike other programming languages, JavaScript does not define different data types for numbers like int, float etc. There's just the ```Number```data type: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Number

Comment: Maybe show us the code you used to try to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.getAttribute('value')` instead of `.value` to get the values

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(e => console.log(e.getAttribute('value')))
```

```html
<li id='1' value='1.0'><a href='#'>No Activity</a></li>
<li id='2' value='1.4'><a href='#'>Low Activity</a></li>
<li id='3' value='1.8'><a href='#'>Middle Activity</a></li>
<li id='4' value='2.2'><a href='#'>High Activity</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li id='1' value='1.0'><a href='#'>No Activity</a></li>
<li id='2' value='1.4'><a href='#'>Low Activity</a></li>
<li id='3' value='1.8'><a href='#'>Middle Activity</a></li>
<li id='4' value='2.2'><a href='#'>High Activity</a></li>

<script>
for(var i=0; i<4; i++) {
    var str = document.getElementsByTagName("li")[i].getAttribute("value");
    var flt = parseFloat(str);
    console.log(flt);
}
</script>
```